# React useEffect and useRef

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

so i got this useEffect function:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
      getDoH().then((response) => {
        initialResponse.current = response.data;
        console.log(response.data)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }); 
      console.log(initialResponse.current)
    }, []);
```

The getDoH is a axios.get function and the initialResponse is :

```
const initialResponse = useRef();
```

which im using to avoid some issues.
The point is for the page to get a group of values from my backend on the first render and save it in the "initialResponse" so i can use it later in other functions.

but my

```
console.log(initialResponse.current)
```

keeps coming back as "Undfeined", in other words i cant seem to save me response value into it. any idea why or how to fix it ?

Comment: It won't show up, because the `.then` runs after your console.log runs, because it's a promise. Why don't you store it in the state?

Comment: I'm sure that if you look at your `log` order, your third log prints before the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem statement isn't inside your `.then()` block, which means that you can't be certain that the `.then()` block has run yet by that time. Network calls are asynchronous, so Javascript charges ahead with execution instead of waiting. If you want to see what that value is after the call *has* returned, you should put your `console.log(initialResponse.current)` statement inside the `.then()` block.

Keep in mind that this means you won't necessarily have data there on first render. You should write your code to accommodate that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a validation of `initialResponse` before:

```
    useEffect(
        () => {
          if(initialResponse && initialResponse.current){
           getDoH().then((response) => {
            initialResponse.current = response.data;
            console.log(response.data)
           }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
           }); 
           console.log(initialResponse.current)
          }
        }, [initialResponse, getDoH]);
```

And add `initialResponse` as a prop of the useEffect hook.

If you cant declare `getDoH` inside the useEffect, add it as a prop is a good practice.

Comment: That did not fix the isse.

Comment: How is `initialResponse.current` going to be fulfilled on the first render? If that is precisely the variable that the user wants to fulfil? Moreover, putting refs in the dep array does not work, it's not supposed to do that.

Comment: please add a codepen (or similar) with your code and I could help you more. @Mr.Gomer